# Spreading over multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I know that this must be answered somewhere, but I cant seem to find a solution.

I have the following

```
id qid val
A   X   5
A   Y   4
A   Z   3
B   X   2
B   Y   1
```

I would like it to look like this

```
id  X Y Z
A   5 4 3 
B   2 1 NA
```

Where each `id` has a unique column.

Here is the data for easy copy-paste

```
tribble(
  ~id, ~qid, ~val,
   "A",  "X",   5,
   "A",  "Y",   4,
   "A",  "Z",   3,
   "B",  "X",   2,
   "B",  "Y",   1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`dcast` from `reshape2`

```
dcast(dat, id ~ qid, value.var = "val")
```

Comment: When you provide an answer make more disctriptive so that most of them can understand